# Android - Using Indeterminate ProgressBar with another Thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to use the indeterminate progress bar from when the user clicks a button to when the email is sent. I am having problems with the thread that I open up to send the email and the progress bar I think. Right now it just crashes when the two are close together and I wasn't sure if there is a smart way to enable the progress bar (basically I just want the animation of the swirling circle while the emails are sent so that the user has some feedback that something is happening in the background).

OnCreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    setContentView(R.layout.signin_page);

    verify_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verify_button);
    signin_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin_button);

    staysignedin = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.staysignedinCheck);

    link4help = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);

    gmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signin_email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signin_password);

    email_success = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.email_authenticate_success);
    password_success = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.password_authenticate_success);

    email_success.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    password_success.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    signin_button.setEnabled(false);

    verify_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    signin_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    link4help.setOnClickListener(this);

    final float scale = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    staysignedin.setPadding(staysignedin.getPaddingLeft() + (int)(10.0f * scale + 0.5f),
            staysignedin.getPaddingTop(),
            staysignedin.getPaddingRight(),
            staysignedin.getPaddingBottom());

     /* Setting up handler for ProgressBar */
    //b = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_verify);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

}
```

OnClick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    //Log.e("verify clicked","hi");
    switch(v.getId()){


    case R.id.verify_button:

        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){


                String gmailString = gmail.getText().toString();
                String passString = password.getText().toString();
                String[] recip = new String[]{gmailString};
                String body = "\nThis is a test for the amazing Dictation2Go App!   Created by --";
                    MailAccount a  = new MailAccount(gmailString,passString);
                    try {
                        isGoogleAuthenticated = a.sendEmailTo(recip, "test", body);
                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                           Log.e("failed to connect", "mess: "+e.getMessage());
                           isGoogleAuthenticated = false;
                    }               
            }
        };
        thread.start();

        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        Log.e("END RESULT",String.valueOf(isGoogleAuthenticated));

        if(isGoogleAuthenticated){
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            email_success.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            password_success.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            signin_button.setEnabled(true);
            password.setEnabled(false);
            gmail.setEnabled(false);

            gmail.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.bordersuccess);
            password.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.bordersuccess);
        }else{
            gmail.setText("");
            password.setText("");
        }
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        break;
```

---

**----- Full Solution ---------------------------------------------------------**

in **OnCreate** Method of the Class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.signin_page);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false); //Sets Default value
    //LOOK at Picture #1 for my screen in this state

}
```

in **OnClick** method (I implemented setOnClickLister for this activity)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    switch(v.getId()){


    case R.id.verify_button:


        String gmailString = gmail.getText().toString();
        String passString = password.getText().toString();

        new AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>() {
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                        //LOOK at Picture #2 for my screen in this state
            }

            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
                String gmailString = args[0];
                String[] recip = new String[] { gmailString };
                String passString = args[1];
                String body = args[2];

                MailAccount a  = new MailAccount(gmailString, passString);
                try {
                    return a.sendEmailTo(recip, "test", body);
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    Log.e("failed to connect", "mess: "+e.getMessage());
                    return false;
                } 
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isGoogleAuthenticated) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                if(isGoogleAuthenticated){
                    email_success.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    password_success.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    signin_button.setEnabled(true);
                    password.setEnabled(false);
                    gmail.setEnabled(false);

                    gmail.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.bordersuccess);
                    password.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.bordersuccess);
                }else{
                    gmail.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                }
            }
        }.execute(gmailString, passString, "test complete");
        //LOOK at Picture #3 for my screen in this state

        break;
```

---

**Picture #1** onCreate

[image: Picture #1 onCreate]

---

**Picture #2** onClick - Loading

[image: Picture #2 onClick - Loading]

---

**Picture #3** Finished Loading

[image: Picture #3 Finished Loading]

Comment: First, always post the stack trace for crashes.  Second, doing a thread.join in the onClick like that will freeze up your entire app making the phone unresponsive.  Its something you should never do on the main thread.  It also may be the cause of your crash, you may be killed by the system watchdog timer (the timer that kills apps that appear to be stuck).

Comment: Instead of using a Thread, why not try AsyncTask. It will taking care everything for you.

Comment: Yeah, AsyncTaask is definately the way to go. Thanks guys! I'm going to add some pics and stuff for a better explanation because I think it will be helpful for others in the future. @Wenhui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your onClick method you will want to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Using AsyncTask means that you don't need to worry about writing your own threading code. As noted in the comments the join that you are doing will block the main thread, potentially causing your app to stop responding. Perhaps you will want something along the lines of;

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String gmailString = gmail.getText().toString();
    String passString = password.getText().toString();

    new AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>() {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
            String gmailString = args[0];
            String[] recip = new String[] { gmailString };
            String passString = args[1];
            String body = args[2];

            MailAccount a  = new MailAccount(gmailString, passString);
            try {
                return a.sendEmailTo(recip, "test", body);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                Log.e("failed to connect", "mess: "+e.getMessage());
                return false;
            } 
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isGoogleAuthenticated) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            // Do the rest of your UI updates here
        }
    }.execute(gmailString, passString, body);
}
```

Comment: Yup, this solution is spot on! I knew there had to be an easier way to set this up. The only thing I had to change in your code was in the protected onPostExecute(Boolean isGoogleAuthenticated) to protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isGoogleAuthenticated). Can the onPostExecute return all types? Just curious... Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I've fixed the method signature. But yeah onPostReturn can receive a parameter of any type that is defined as the 3rd generic argument in the original AsyncTask definition.

Comment: Just a quick thing to add here, you should probably store a reference to this task in your activity and make sure you cancel it in onDestroy() (and null it out when it completes). Then in your onPostExecute() you should make sure you wrap all of your UI updating code in a check to see if you cancelled the task. (That or use a setRetainInstance(true) fragment).